# Datahub Hybris installation unclear

Tags: hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud

I am following the Getting Started with Data Hub guide to install standalone data hub. the guide mentions that hsqldb is already configured after datahub.webapp.war file and it will use database instance with the name of 'integration' with an administrative user named 'hybris' with the password 'hybris'.

I wanted to know two things; 1) How to connect to hsql server for datahub and check the item-types 2) Are we supposed to create this database named 'integration' and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the default Hsql configuration for the Datahub :

```
#main storage
dataSource.className=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource
dataSource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:datahub
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=

#media storage
media.dataSource.className=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource
media.dataSource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dhmedia
media.dataSource.username=sa
media.dataSource.password=
```

You don't need to create anything for this to work.

If you want to check the item types you could use a client like : http://www.sql-workbench.net, but bear in mind that only one connection can be active at a time, therefore I would suggest to use Mysql (See configuration example below) :

```
dataSource.className=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/integration?useConfigs=maxPerformance
dataSource.username=user
dataSource.password=pass
```